# Uploading html to Bluemix

Tags: java, html, ibm-cloud

I'm pushing the war file to **Bluemix**, but the only thing that changes are the things I changed in java files, but when I change html file, nothing changes, should I be pushing html separately?
I'm using eclipse and pushing it by using **cmd**.

Comment: We're gooing to need more details than that. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider revising the question.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the html is in the proper location. create a WAR first and then push